# Run linux command based on existing file in a directory

Tags: linux, bash, directory

In `/dev/usb` directory sometimes I have `lp0` and sometimes `lp1`. How can I change the following command to change the `--name`
based on the content of `/dev/usb`? I.e. if I have `lp0` in the `/dev/usb` directory I get:

```
TEST=`udevadm info --attribute-walk --name=/dev/usb/lp0 | grep "serial}==\"VL" | sed -n -e 's/^.*serial}==\"VL//p' | sed 's/\"//g'`
```

and if there is lp1 in /dev/usb/ directory:

```
TEST=`udevadm info --attribute-walk --name=/dev/usb/lp1 | grep "serial}==\"VL" | sed -n -e 's/^.*serial}==\"VL//p' | sed 's/\"//g'`
```

How can I save the content of /dev/usb in a variable (lp0 or lp1) and then use it in the above command?

Comment: Is this a question? I'm not sure what you're asking here.

Comment: Can you provide more context on when the name changes? What do you mean by 'sometimes'? Do you mean the same device on the same machine will sometimes have a different name, or are you talking about running the script on different machines which may have different device names from each other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could write:

```
lp=( /dev/usb/lp? )
TEST=$( udevadm info --attribute-walk --name=${f[0]} ... )
```

the `?` wildcard matches any 1 character.

Answer (score 0):

You can test for readability of the lpX devices as follows:

```
 if test -r /dev/usb/lp0; then
    NAME=/dev/usb/lp0
 elif test -r /dev/usb/lp1; then
    NAME=/dev/usb/lp1
 else
    printf '%s\n' "could not find lp0 or lp1" >&2
    exit 1
 fi
 TEST=$(udevadm info --attribute-walk --name=$NAME ...)
```